# Re-position navbar further down when the user scrolls to the top of the page (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-position, navbar

I have a problem on my website where my alt-navbar (under the main navbar) positions itself too high up on the page, behind the main navbar, when the user scrolls to the top of the page.

The main navbar and the alt-navbar are correctly aligned when scrolling other areas of the page.
What i need to do is to "offset" the alt-navbar using jQuery when the user has scrolled to the top of the page, so it gets positioned a bit further down.
I don't know what jQuery function to use to get the "top of the page" position value (*For example: Do something when document is at top position*).

I'll send 2 images too show what i mean in more detail along with the source code below.

**IMAGE 1:**

[image: Correctly-aligned-navbars]

**IMAGE 2**
[image: alt-nav-needs-down-offset-value]

**jQuery Code:**

```
   // Hide Header on on scroll down
   var didScroll;
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   var delta = 5;
   var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

   $(window).scroll(function(event){
       didScroll = true;
   });

    setInterval(function() {
       if (didScroll) {
           hasScrolled();
           didScroll = false;
       }
   }, 250);

   function hasScrolled() {
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       
       // Make sure they scroll more than delta
       if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
           return;
       
       // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
       // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
       if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
           // Scroll Down
           $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
       } else {
           // Scroll Up
           if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
               $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
           }
       }
       
       lastScrollTop = st;
   }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scroll_functionality.js">
    </script>
<style>
#navbar {
  height: 0em;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.75rem 0rem 1.75rem 0rem;
  background: white;
  align-items: center;

  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #d0d8d9;
}
#find-your-memory {
font-family: "Contrail One";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="main-flex-container">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>    
                    <li> 
                        <a href="https://swiftwintekstore.com/pages/under-dev" rel="Our Top Picks" title="Top Picks"> 
                            Top Picks
                            <span style="color: blue; font-size: x-small; font-weight: bold; margin-left: .275em;"> 
                            (New)
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>     
                    <li id="find-your-memory"> 
                        <a href="https://swiftwintekstore.com/pages/memory-ssd-selector" rel="Find the best Memory or SSD drive for your needs" title="Micron Memory Selector"> 
                            Find your Memory
                            <span style="color: blue; font-size: x-small; font-weight: bold; margin-left: .275em;"> 
                            (Upcoming)
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>             
                    <li> 
                        <a href="https://swiftwintekstore.com/blogs/news" rel="News about our products and technology" title="News Feed"> 
                            News
                        </a>
                    </li>      
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-flex-container {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
  #navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
  }
  #navbar a {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-size: small;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: 0px;
  }
  a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 70, 14);
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #navbar a {
      padding-bottom: 0.175rem;
    }
  }
  header {
    height: 38px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5.1rem;
    transition: top 0.1s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .nav-up {
    top: -40px;
  }
```

I haven't really tried anything myself yet due to the lack of knowledge of the problem.